# How to use basic deleteview

Tags: python, django

I start use `DeleteView` of `django.views.generic`.

However I am still confused about `DeleteView`

Document says you don't need to do anything in `DeleteView` apart from `UpdateView`,`CreateView`

So,,,,is this correct??

It doesn't delete the item.

in `urls.py`

```
path('preaction/<int:pk>/delete', PreActionDeleteView.as_view(),
     name="pre-action-delete"),
```

in `views.py`

```
class PreActionDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = PreAction
    success_url = reverse_lazy("pre-action-list")

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        messages_text = "deleted"
        messages.success(self.request, messages_text)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Document says you don't need to do anything in DeleteView apart from

Since you are overriding `delete()` method, you have to delete the specified object manually which in you case is just to call `self.object.delete()`:

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    success_url = self.get_success_url()
    self.object.delete()

    messages_text = "deleted"
    messages.success(self.request, messages_text)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

To get more information on how things get handled, see this well-structured [flow diagram](https://www.brennantymrak.com/articles/deleteviewdiagram).

Comment: Thank you I overrided delete wrongly. It solves my problem

Answer (score 1):

Don't override `delete()` method. It's much clearer to do such things in `form_valid()`:

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin


class BookDeleteView(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = PreAction
    success_url = reverse_lazy("pre-action-list")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data_to_return = super().form_valid(form)
        messages_text = "deleted"
        messages.success(self.request, messages_text)
        return data_to_return
```

Just in case, you usually need to return `super()` of the method, that is normally in the `View`.

Also you don't need to use `return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)`, because it's standard behaviour of `DeleteView` to redirect to `success_url`.

Comment: Thank you I wrongly override delete. `form_valid` is also good practice.